# Can I pass in node options (e.g., IPC=true) when composing nodes using the CLI or launch files

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This demo shows how IPC works: https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/intra_process_demo

The nodes in this demo are all defined such that use_intra_process_communications is initialized to true when the node is constructed.

This demo shows how composition works: https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/composition

The nodes in this demo are all defined such that somebody -- the node container? -- passes in node options when the nodes are instantiated. This appears to be a requirement for composition.

Is there a way to specify node options (e.g., use_intra_process_communications=true) using the ros2 CLI or using launch files? I'm not seeing anything in the Python launch code.

Edit: I'm skimming the rclcpp and rcl code, and I see that some arguments are parsed (params, log handling, etc.), but I don't see anything to turn IPC on/off. Is there a feature request / bug tracking this?

Edit 2: It appears that the answer is "no", and this is the issue: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/492

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328188/can-i-pass-in-node-options-(e.g.,-ipc=true)-when-composing-nodes-using-the-cli-or-launch-files/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2019-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is possible from a launch file using `extra_arguments`, e.g.:

```
def generate_launch_description():
    """Generate launch description with multiple components."""
    container = ComposableNodeContainer(
            node_name='my_container',
            node_namespace='',
            package='rclcpp_components',
            node_executable='component_container',
            composable_node_descriptions=[
                ComposableNode(
                    package='composition',
                    node_plugin='composition::Talker',
                    node_name='talker',
                    extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms': True}]),
                ComposableNode(
                    package='composition',
                    node_plugin='composition::Listener',
                    node_name='listener',
                    extra_arguments=[{'use_intra_process_comms': True}])
            ],
            output='screen',
    )
```

It's also possible to pass `extra_arguments` on the command line, see documentation at `ros2 component load --help`.

I believe that this was introduced in Eloquent.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2019-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shivaang12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27030/shivaang12/) on 2020-01-27**:
Does this works? I wanted to do the same thing but cannot able to pass the parameters this way. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using foxy

**Comment by [FabianMene](https://answers.ros.org/users/40407/fabianmene/) on 2020-01-30**:
It does work in eloquent.

**Comment by [shivaang12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27030/shivaang12/) on 2020-01-30**:
I think I have asked wrong question (sorry, I just realized). I am trying to pass params to the composable node. Do you know how it can be done? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I figured out from this https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/715